# How to show currently playing audio on Android with audio_service?

Tags: flutter, audio-service

I've been using this package for couple of apps already. Always used one-isolate version.

On the iOS, I see this package successfully registers the audio on control center but on Android, I don't see control buttons anymore. Only a notification about that app being running on the background. Did I miss something in the setup or is it a bug?

[image]

Comment: Your question could be improved by explaining what you did in both the setup and also the code related to showing the notification.

Comment: Thanks, I follow the same instructions for setup on one isolate branch. For notifications, I don't have a code specific code. I just play an audio file and also I have skip, stop, pause etc. controls setup in _broadcastState like in example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I'm initiating the service, I was overriding the       androidNotificationIcon with an incorrect value.

```
  androidNotificationIcon: 'mipmap/launcher_icon'
```

Probably because I've copied pasted some code from my previous application. I removed this line now and it points to the its default value.

```
{String androidNotificationIcon = 'mipmap/ic_launcher'}
```

Everything works.